# Displaying JPEG image on the face of a button control using MFC

Tags: image, mfc, jpeg

I need to display a JPEG image on the face of a button control added onto FormView. 
The problem I faced is incorporating the .jpeg images into the .rc file. Something stops me from displaying the image. I am getting a blank control. (I set the button to owner draw of course.)

I tried using a picture control over the button control and it still wont display the resource.

There is no MFC feature pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to check/try. Are you using the GDI+ bitmap to draw the bitmap? If not, that's probably the best way. Alternatively I'd recommend [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) to load it into a CBitmap as I've always found it very straightforward to use. Secondly, make sure you store your jpeg as a "JPG" type in your .rc file. If you try and store it as a BITMAP resource then you'll have all sorts of problems.

Comment: Thanks I got the images to display on the buttons, but they seem to have lost their functionality.

Comment: For some more information, I created a class derived from CButton. Then used the OnPaint function to draw the Button's Image using CxImage.

Comment: What functionality have you lost? Are you sure it's to do with drawing the jpeg rather than something else in your custom CButton class?

Comment: The Owner Draw property of all buttons was on. And after loading the images (as "JPG" resources), the click of those buttons wasn't calling the respective button click functions. I unchecked this property and it is working okay now.